# rxjs - deprecated subscribe with multiple parameter

Tags: rxjs

`rxjs` 6.4. started to deprecate `subscribe` with multiple parameters. To some extend I understand but on a practical level I have my problems. Especially when I specify the type received parameter. E.g.

```
subscribe((response: boolean | LibDto) => {
            this.errorCmpt.showMsgShort('save success');
            }, () =>
            this.errorCmpt.showMsgShort('save failure')
        )
```

When I try to follow the given [link](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments) than I thought I can rewrite the function like:

```
subscribe({
        complete:(response: boolean | LibDto) => {
            this.errorCmpt.showMsgShort('save success');
    }, error: () =>
            this.errorCmpt.showMsgShort('save failure')
            })
```

But this fails

```
  Overload 1 of 3, '(observer?: Partial<Observer<boolean | LibDto>>): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Type '(response: any) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(next: (value: boolean | LibDto) => void): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ complete: (response: any) => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: boolean | LibDto) => void'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'complete' does not exist in type '(value: boolean | LibDto) => void'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(next?: (value: boolean | LibDto) => void, error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ complete: (response: any) => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: boolean | LibDto) => void'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'complete' does not exist in type '(value: boolean | LibDto) => void'.  ref-source-dialog.component.ts
```

If I try `complete` with a function without parameters it works. How to write it correctly?

Answer (score 2):

### RxJS Observers

RxJS observers have 3 callbacks that an observable will call. Here's a simplified interface:

```ts
interface Observer<T>{
  next: (a:T) => void;
  error: (e:Error) => void;
  complete: () => void;
}
```

These two calls are treated (basically the same)

```ts
stream$.subscribe(console.log);
stream$.subscribe({next: console.log});
```

That is to say, if you give subscribe a function, it will assume the function is for the `Observer`'s `next` callback.

If you look at the interface above, you'll note that an `Observer`'s `complete` callback doesn't take any arguments. You can't get a response inside a complete callback.

### Toward an Answer

Perhaps you meant:

```ts
subscribe({
  next: (response: boolean | LibDto) => {
    this.errorCmpt.showMsgShort('save success');
  }, 
  error: () => {
    this.errorCmpt.showMsgShort('save failure');
  }
});
```

or

```ts
subscribe({
  complete: () => {
    this.errorCmpt.showMsgShort('save success');
  }, 
  error: () => {
    this.errorCmpt.showMsgShort('save failure');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thx for the response. Is there as well a docu for the `subscribe` function? I found how it is deprecated but didn't find something about the syntax.

Comment: As well the question: what is the match to the current return of the `subscribe(()=>fn)`? Is it `next` or `complete`? Therefore the question for the docu.